# preventing pipes on an outside wall from freezing

Tags: insulation, pex, heat

[image: pipe casing]I remodeled my cabin to a four season home. My pipes have frozen twice. I removed casing because I was planning to install heat tape. I noticed my builder had not put any installation behind the pipes. I do have styrofoam covers on the pipes, but that is it. It is a Northern exposure wall and the wind comes right at it. The heat tape I have seen is not  recommended for use inside of a wall. I am wondering if I insulated the wall behind the pipes, and purchased better insulating material for the pipes if this would suffice. Would cutting 1 inch holes into the casing allow warm room air to enter into the casing? Lastly, a friend recommended stainless steel heatape. Does anybody know anything about 
  this, and where I can purchase it? what about heat eleents that go inside the pipe such as 1" BRASS NPT SCREW PLUG HEATER 60 - 86 WSI for instance

Comment: What is casing?  Is it stud space (void in wall)?

Comment: my builder used 2x4s to hide the pipes at the ceiling. Pipes are not in stud space. They are on the inside of the car siding that is used to cover stud space. Thanks!

Comment: Smart builders in cold climates don't put plumbing in outside walls.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get insulation between those pipes and the outside wall of the cabin and lots of it.  Don't insulated the warm side of those pipes.  That is the only heat that keeps the pipes from freezing.  I wouldn't pursue the heat tape idea.  Put all of your effort into insulation the cold side of those pipes.  And keep the interior of the cabin above 60* all year. You will eventually get it.  Good Luck. You can always let the water trickle from a faucet on those cold and windy nights. Additional thought, in general the exterior wall of he cabin must be well insulated.  Hope this helps. Good Luck.